# how can we set horizontal space between two views using autolayouts programatically(using constraintWithItem model formate)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in ios in my application i want add two UIviews programatically using auto-layouts(constraintWithItem model) but horizental space is not setting b/w this two view according to my code screen is coming like first screen

### My code is below

```
 //Applying autolayouts for myview1
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];

       // Applying autolayouts for myview2

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myview2,myview3);


        [myview1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f]];

        [myview1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f]];

   [myview1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:80.0f]];


        NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myview2]-10-[myview3]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

        [myview1 addConstraints:horizontalConstraintsforbuttons];

       // Applying autolayouts for myview3

        [myview1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f]];

        [myview1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f]];

        [myview1 addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:myview3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:myview1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:80.0f]];
```

[image]

but i want to get result like second screen please help me some one

[image]

Comment: trailing constraints for view1 to superview is not correct...you should make trailing constraints to view1 with view 2

Comment: I assume myview1 is the gray one and myview2 is blue and myview3 orange and that 2 and 3 are subviews of 1?

Comment: yes 2@3 are subviews of 1

Comment: You need to update your question with information on how you want the widths of myview2 and myview3 to be set.

Answer (score 0):

2 errors here:

1) You are adding 2 leading constraints to view 2 and 2 trailing constraints to view 3. One comes from a line of code ("NSLayoutAttributeLeading" etc) and the second from the visual format

2) You're not telling auto layout in any way how to set the width for myview2 and myview3. So one view gets all the available width and the other 0.

You can fix both problems by changing

```
    NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myview2]-10-[myview3]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
```

to

```
NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[myview2(==myview3)]-10-[myview3]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
```

This gets rid of the extra leading and trailing constraints and tells auto layout that the width of myview2 and myview3 should be equal.

Comment: Yes Stefan but according to my requirement "myview2" and "myview3" widths should not be equal

Comment: What are your requirements? Please update your question to include all details.

Comment: Yes stefen but according to my requirment  "myview2" and "myview3" widths should not be equal that's i changed your code like(NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[myview2(200)]-10-[myview3]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];) but in portraint mode it's ok but in landscpae mode both widths are applying for one another

Comment: Did your change solve your problem or do you have any remaining issues?

Comment: i mean i want get my result like above second screen please help if i apply constant width for one view that view width is not changing even in landscape mode but i want grow the width according to i screens sizes

Comment: You need to be specific about how you want the widths to relate. Examples: 1) view2 should use 40% and view3 60% space. 2) view3 should be 20px wider than view2 3) view2 should be 200px and view 3 should use the remaining space